# Improving small images for data extraction

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

In Open CV or with Pillow library how can we improve below images for tesseract.

[image: Images]

[image: Images]

[image: Images]

I tried below code with multiple options like thresholding, blur, enchance, however not able to improve.

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))

img_medianBlur = cv2.blur(img, (3 , 3))

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img_medianBlur))

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)

ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(img,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(th3))
```

Comment: A lot of that noise is likely caused by a poor choice of codec for storage of input data -- JPEG is lossy, and it's intended for photographs, not synthetic images like this.

Comment: I am trying with PNG, also using some other mechanism to convert pdf to image so that aspect ratio and dpi is maintained across the processing pipeline. Will update my findings soon

Comment: If it is consistently stretched, try training tesseract with a custom font - https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/tess4/TrainingTesseract-4.00.html. Although, my gut instinct is garbage in, garbage out. These images look like very low quality extracts, I would start with improving that first.

Comment: Overall, there is no one-size-fits-all solution for improving the results of text extraction from small and heavily blurred images. You may need to experiment with different techniques and combinations of techniques to find the approach that works best for your specific situation. With just three sample pictures it's hard to judge what you need... You could try to sharpen the image via `cv2.filter2D()`?

Comment: You may want to accept any slightest bit of helpful answer before the bounty expires and disappears.

Comment: It'll look clearer if you put `<hr>` tags or something between the images (Suggested Edits are full of course, or I would suggest it there).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first two images are the result of motion blur.

If denoising filters, such as Gaussian, don't work, I suggest research on two topics, `motion deblur` and `deconvolution`.

You might want to check out this OpenCV tutorial on [deblurring filter](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/d3c/tutorial_out_of_focus_deblur_filter.html)
and [motion deblur filter](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dfd/tutorial_motion_deblur_filter.html).

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-IINpceX6k) explains mathematical aspect of the algorithm.

I'll come back to improve my answer if time permits.

Comment: Tried with wiener filter to deblur not giving expected output